# Unable to access video files in ReactJS: No errors are visible in the console

Tags: reactjs, file-structure

I am trying to access videos in ReactJS but I do not know why it is constantly not accepting them, the console neither shows errors.

I have tried `../assests/videos/video-2.mp4` and other variants still I am not able to see the video on display and neither the console shows an error

**Following is the code and file structure of my project:**
[image: Folder and File structure]

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your code as text. Do not attach images of the code. You can attach an image to show your folder structure but not to show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move videos inside the `public` folder

**Example**: Your **file-structure** will be like

```
public/assets/videos/video-1.mp4
public/assets/videos/video-2.mp4
```

Then your path `/assets/videos/video-1.mp4` will be working

Comment: But it's not playing the video, can u suggest something for that too.

Comment: Also, as I saw that people suggest placing the assets folder in src so that no ambiguity shall arise. As one answer on stack overflow, they said that " if assets are placed in public then the image or video can be called using two different links which is a bad practice".

Comment: `<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>`

try this way